# Alexa cannot recognize the utterence or sent the right intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing an Alexa skill currently. I customed an intent called "PlayNextChannelIntent" with utterence like "next channel" and "next feed", however, alexa always sent my request to the built-in Next intent(I use this intent for other actions). Then, I changed my utterence to "forward channel" or "plus channel", but alexa can not recognize my voice and cannot sent intent at all. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Before testing with voice, can you check if you have configured your intents correctly by typing instead of using your voice in the Test tab of the Skill Builder?

Comment: What happens when you say plus channel (take a look at the json output, see which intent is called)? Please share your interaction model json file